# Prove that if $\alpha \geq1$ and $n\geq 2\alpha \log(2\alpha)$ then $n \geq \alpha \log(2n)$

Tags: inequality, logarithms

I want to prove this statement:

$\alpha \geq1$ and $n\geq 2\alpha \log(2\alpha)$ then $n \geq  \alpha \log(2n)$

It seemed pretty simple but I couldn't do too much. My first attempt was

$$ \log(n) \geq \log ( 2\alpha \log(2\alpha) ) $$

But this attempt didn't look promising. Could you give me a hint?

Comment: I don't see $a$ anywhere in the final result or in the other condition. So how are we expected to use $a \ge 1$?

Comment: @Haris Yeah, it was a typo ($\alpha$ )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume, for the sake of contradiction, that there exists $(\alpha, n)$ such that $\alpha \ge 1$ and $n \ge 2\alpha \ln (2\alpha)$ and $n < \alpha \ln (2n)$.

We have
$\alpha \ln(2n) > n \ge 2\alpha \ln(2\alpha)$ which results in $n \ge 2\alpha^2$.
Thus, we have
$n < \alpha \ln(2n) \le \sqrt{n/2}\ln(2n)$
which results in $\sqrt{2n} < \ln(2n)$,
or $\mathrm{e}^{\sqrt{2n}} < 2n$.
However, using $\mathrm{e}^x \ge 1 + x + \frac12 x^2 + \frac16 x^3$ for all $x > 0$,
we have
$$\mathrm{e}^{\sqrt{2n}}
\ge 1 + \sqrt{2n} + \frac12 \sqrt{2n}^2 + \frac16 \sqrt{2n}^3 > 2n.$$
Contradiction.

Comment: I don't understand the last inequality. Is it due to $(\frac{1}{2})\sqrt{2n}^{2} = n$?

Comment: @xenuti By AM-GM, we have $\sqrt{2n}  + \frac16 \sqrt{2n}^3 \ge \sqrt{2n}  + \frac{1}{16} \sqrt{2n}^3 \ge 2\sqrt{ \sqrt{2n}  \cdot \frac{1}{16} \sqrt{2n}^3 } =  n$. Also, $\frac12 \sqrt{2n}^2 = n$.

Answer (score 2):

If ${a}\geq 1$, then we know that $\log(a)\geq0$ $\Rightarrow n\geq 0$.
Substituting $ p = \alpha\log(2\alpha)$. We can clearly see the following:
$$n\geq 2p$$ And because the numbers are positive then
$$n\geq p$$
EDIT:
Considering the change of what we have to prove:
Here is the updated variant.
If $n\geq 2\alpha\log(2\alpha)$, and all of the terms are positive, we can say that $n  = 2\alpha\log(2\alpha) + \psi_1$ Where $\psi_1$ is some number greater than $0$. Plugging this into the second inequality we get what we have to prove:
$$2\alpha\log(2\alpha) + \psi_1 = \alpha\log(4\alpha\log(2\alpha) + 2\psi_1) + \psi_2 $$
$${(2\alpha)}^{2\alpha}e^{\psi_1}=(4\alpha \log(2\alpha)+2\psi_1)^{a}e^{\psi_2}$$
$$(2\alpha)^{2\alpha}=((4\alpha\log(2\alpha)+2\psi_1)^{\frac{1}{2}})^{2a}e^{\psi_2-\psi_1}$$
$$e^{\frac{\psi_1-\psi_2}{2a}}=\left(\frac{\sqrt{(4\alpha\log(2\alpha)+2\psi_1)}}{2\alpha}\right) $$
Let $\psi_3=e^{\frac{\psi_1-\psi_2}{2a}}$, and we know that $\psi_3 \gt 0$, so we only have to prove:
$$\left(\frac{\sqrt{(4\alpha\log(2\alpha)+2\psi_1)}}{2\alpha}\right) \gt 0$$
And since all of the terms are positive (including $\psi_1$), this will never equal or be less than $0$.

Comment: I´m sorry. I made a mistake. I have to prove that $n \geq \alpha log(2n)$

Comment: @Masd I have a question. I think that $\left(\frac{\sqrt{(4\alpha\log(2\alpha)+2\psi_1)}}{2\alpha}\right) > 0$ and $e^{\frac{\psi_1-\psi_2}{2a}} > 0$ does not imply $\psi_2 \ge 0$. 
You need to prove that
 $\psi_2 < 0$ and  $e^{\frac{\psi_1-\psi_2}{2a}}=\left(\frac{\sqrt{(4\alpha\log(2\alpha)+2\psi_1)}}{2\alpha}\right) > 0$ is impossible. In other words, you need to prove that $$e^{\frac{\psi_1}{2a}}\ge \left(\frac{\sqrt{(4\alpha\log(2\alpha)+2\psi_1)}}{2\alpha}\right).$$

Comment: By definition $\psi_2$ is bigger than 0

Comment: @Masd I think that you have to prove that there always exists $\psi_2\ge 0$ such that $2\alpha\log(2\alpha) + \psi_1 = \alpha\log(4\alpha\log(2\alpha) + 2\psi_1) + \psi_2$; in other words, $2\alpha\log(2\alpha) + \psi_1 = \alpha\log(4\alpha\log(2\alpha) + 2\psi_1) + \psi_2$ implies $\psi_2 \ge 0$ (this is what you want to prove rather than definition).

Comment: I was just rephrasing the statement that what we have to prove, is all